# Can you trigger an AWS Lambda from the creation of an AWS Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I've written an AWS Lambda that's triggered by the creation of an EC2 instance that checks if the required tags have been set. From the Terraform file:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_event_rule" "check-ec2-tags" {
    description = "Capture each EC2 instance creation"
    event_pattern = <<PATTERN
{
  "source": [ "aws.ec2" ],
  "detail-type": [ "EC2 Instance State-change Notification" ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [ "running" ]
  }
}
PATTERN
}
```

I want to do the same thing for AWS Lambdas - whenever a new lambda is created I want to make sure it has the required tags. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the `.tfstate` file in s3 and a lambda can be triggered on the `S3Event`. This lambda function can extract the resource name from the `.tfstate` file and can validate any resource available in `.tfstate` file.

Comment: That assumes the lambda is created through Terraform, but if that was the case I can use Sentinel to check the tags.